# Accessing Swagger Documentation with JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I have generated an app server only through jhipster using only.

```
yo jhipster --skip-client
```

It had generated all the necessary api calls I needed however upon accessing

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
```

I ended on a 404. I was under the impression that swagger is included however it cant seem to be accessed, although the swagger api endpoints is available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't since you are only generating the rest apis. if you want to see the api-docs follow the instructions mentioned [here](http://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#swagger-ui-documentation-29)

Once you have succesfully cloned the said [repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)

open dist/index.html and simply paste the source there

http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

it should look like something like this[image]

Comment: I think the first link is outdated hence the answer becomes incoherent, as the first is talking about swagger-editor and the second swagger-ui.

Can you explain here what we need to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following dependency. You are missing the dependency here.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```